# ¿Como realizar un CASE con información que no exista en una tabla MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Pondré un ejemplo sencillo de lo que quiero hacer, tengo la tabla `Usuarios` la cual se actualiza cada 90 segundos en este ejemplo la tabla tendra la siguiente información:

```
Usuarios

Nombre    Puerto      Ip
  Juan        4      192.168.1.1
  Juan        9      192.168.1.1
  Jorge       8      192.168.1.2
  Roberto     3      192.168.1.1
```

Pero en alguna actualización puede llegar a tener la siguiente información:

```
Usuarios

    Nombre    Puerto      Ip
      Juan        4      192.168.1.1
      Juan        9      192.168.1.1
      Jorge       2      192.168.1.2
      Jorge       8      192.168.1.2
      Roberto     3      192.168.1.1
      Roberto     7      192.168.1.1
```

Para saber en que equipo se encuentra cada usuario hago la siguiente consulta:

```
 Select Nombre, Puerto, Ip,
         CASE WHEN Nombre='Juan' and Puerto>5 and Ip='192.168.1.1' THEN '20' ELSE
         CASE WHEN Nombre='Juan' and Puerto<6 and Ip='192.168.1.1' THEN '19' ELSE
         CASE WHEN Nombre='Jorge' and Puerto>5 and Ip='192.168.1.2' THEN '18' ELSE
         CASE WHEN Nombre='Jorge' and Puerto<6 and Ip='192.168.1.2' THEN '17' ELSE
         CASE WHEN Nombre='Roberto' and Puerto>5 and Ip='192.168.1.1' THEN '16' ELSE
         CASE WHEN Nombre='Roberto' and Puerto<6 and Ip='192.168.1.1' THEN '15'
         END END END END END END AS Equipo
From Usuarios
Order by Usuarios Desc
```

Mi resultado considerando la primer tabla es el siguiente:

```
Nombre    Puerto      Ip              Equipo
  Juan        9      192.168.1.1        20 
  Juan        4      192.168.1.1        19    
  Jorge       8      192.168.1.2        18
  Roberto     3      192.168.1.1        15
```

Como pueden observar omite los Equipos 17 y 16 ya que no se cumple el `case`, entonces yo quiero realizar una consulta en la cual me identifique que equipos se encuentran sin usar algo como esto:

```
Nombre    Puerto      Ip              Equipo    Estado
  Juan        9      192.168.1.1        20      En_uso
  Juan        4      192.168.1.1        19      En_uso
  Jorge       8      192.168.1.2        18      En_uso
  Jorge       2      192.168.1.2        17      Sin_usar
  Roberto     7      192.168.1.1        16      Sin_usar
  Roberto     3      192.168.1.1        15      En_uso
```

Pero como la tabla se actualiza y cuando los equipos no están en uso simplemente no existe su información en la tabla no se como hacerlo.

PD: La tabla es un ejemplo sencillo así que ignoren la lógica de la información de la tabla, la tabla con la que estoy trabajando no fue realizada por mi

Comment: El resultado de tu `CASE` en tu consulta no puede tener menos filas que las que trae la tabla, ya que no estás haciendo ningún filtro.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Lamak en realidad quiero que tenga mas filas de las que tiene mi tabla, si a eso te referías dices que no se puede?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de realizar los `CASE` con una sola tabla, pon las condiciones en otra tabla y luego haces las comparaciones. Algo mas o menos como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT Rangos.Nombre, Rangos.IP, Usuarios.Puerto, Rangos.Equipo, IF(ISNULL(Usuarios.Puerto),'Sin_usar','En_uso') Estado
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Juan' Nombre, '192.168.1.1' IP, 1 PuertoInicial, 5 PuertoFinal, '19' Equipo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Juan', '192.168.1.1', 6 , 999, '20'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jorge', '192.168.1.2', 1 , 5, '17'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jorge', '192.168.1.2', 6 , 999, '18'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Roberto', '192.168.1.1', 1 , 5, '15'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Roberto', '192.168.1.1', 6 , 999, '16'
) Rangos LEFT JOIN Usuarios 
ON BINARY Rangos.Nombre = BINARY Usuarios.Nombre AND BINARY Rangos.IP = BINARY Usuarios.IP AND Usuarios.Puerto BETWEEN Rangos.PuertoInicial AND Rangos.PuertoFinal
```

Esto consulta debería arrojar el siguiente resultado:

```
Nombre  IP          Puerto    Equipo  Estado
Juan    192.168.1.1 4         19      En_uso
Juan    192.168.1.1 9         20      En_uso
Jorge   192.168.1.2 8         18      En_uso
Roberto 192.168.1.1 3         15      En_uso
Jorge   192.168.1.2           17      Sin_usar
Roberto 192.168.1.1           16      Sin_usar
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Weimar en un momento adaptare la consulta a mi tabla original solo tengo una duda respecto a tu ejemplo, si se tomara en cuenta la 1er tabla que puse en mi ejemplo los campos ´Nombre´, ´IP´ del resultado de tu consulta también saldrían vacíos como el campo ´Puerto´ verdad?

Comment: Si la pregunta es que si usas Usuarios.Nombre en vez de Rangos.Nombre para el resultado final. La respuesta es SI, te saldrían nulos también.

Comment: El Condor, si la respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como correcta. Gracias.

Comment: Si ahorita la marcare solo otra cosa no me queda muy claro lo de los rangos y como la tabla real tiene muchos campos y otras condiciones aun no termino de adaptarla, lo que no me queda  claro es en el filtro de puerto inicial y final, se te paso poner arriba de 5? me refiero a esta parte del código: ´SELECT 'Juan' Nombre, '192.168.1.1' IP, 1 PuertoInicial, 5 PuertoFinal, '19' Equipo´

Comment: Ya comprendí lo del between para los puertos, ya adapte la consulta pero sucede que solo me muestra en Estado: En_uso y sin usar no me las muestra, ya valide y las que no muestra efectivamente no están conectadas el detalle es que no me muestra la información de cuales son las Sin_usar

Comment: Como no se que adaptaciones le hiciste a la consulta es difícil saber que esta pasando, pero por lo que me indicas puede ser que en la consulta estes usando INNER JOIN en vez de LEFT JOIN  o lo invertiste así Usuarios LEFT JOIN Rangos lo que tampoco te funcionaria.

Comment: Básicamente solo cambie nombre de tabla, campos y como agregue las condiciones que en mi problema real son 21 y en el ejemplo que puse eran 6, de hecho el resultado si esta bien, solo que en vez de mostrarme filas con Estatus: Sin_usar simplemente no me muestra esas filas y únicamente muestra las filas con Estatus: En_uso

Comment: Hice una tabla con los mismos datos del ejemplo y ejecute tu consulta y funciona muy bien, el problema debe ser mio :/ pero ya me indicaste el camino, ahora voy a buscar en que estoy fallando gracias.

Comment: Si puedes enviarme o actualizar tu pregunta con la consulta real  que tienes en este momento, me quedaría mas fácil colaborarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias mi estimado pero ya no sera necesario, al adaptar la consulta le agregue un `where` que ya no era necesario porque ya estaba especificado en los rangos, al quitar eso funciono de maravilla, muchísimas gracias

Comment: retomando la pregunta quería hacerte otra consulta respecto al mismo caso, te puedo preguntar por aquí o debo abrir una nueva pregunta?